# DocuSign Formula Tags

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to create formula tags from my DocuSign demo account.
As per your documentation, I have disabled the option "Allow Markup" for my DocuSign demo account.

When I create a formula tag which simply performs simple math operations between two numbers, my formula tag displays the correct result.

When I use the reference tags within the formula tag, my formula tag does not do any calculation and the end result is always zero.

My formula looks something like this..

[Data Field 1] * [Data Field 2]

Where Data Field 1 and Data Field 2 both are tags that allows only numbers to be entered.

Is there anything that I need to add?

Comment: Is this related to the DocuSign API or just DocuSign web console (website)?

Comment: Currently, I am only trying from DocuSign web console.

Comment: Please post this question here: http://community.docusign.com/ Stack overflow is for programming questions